# How to generate DAO classes in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, dao

**Is it possible to generate DAO classes in IntelliJ IDEA**? I found many articles about generating entities but none on generating DAO.

I am using version 11.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it, you can consider using [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) instead via Ant:

> Ant task: The Hibernate3 tools include a unified Ant task that allows you to run schema generation, mapping generation, or Java code generation as part of your build.

---

> The tools for Hibernate provides various tools to use with Hibernate.
>   The primary tools can be used for generating source artifacts such as
>   mapping files, java entities, DAO and other scaffolding code.  The
>   source of this generation can be JDBC database, classes or even just
>   existing mappings.
>
> It uses Hibernate core metamodel to generate from and to the source
>   artifacts. Allowing it to support both top-down, bottom-up and
>   middle-out development.
>
> Hibernate Tools is used in JBoss Tools Hibernate plugins to provide
>   parts of the Eclipse plugins for Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that Intellij does now support this. Follow the guide here:

[New Intellij Functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/generating-persistence-mappings.html?origin=old_help)